# Stack Overflow wmd editor anti-CSRF

Tags: support, markdown, editor

How does Stack Overflow's markdown protect against CSRF attacks? For example, an image generated by markdown like:

```
![alt text][1]
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/users/logout
```

does not log the user off when viewed

Comment: @Tomek - any chance of fixing the english in this question (to the same standard as your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872588/asp-net-mvc-authorization-permission-to-use-model-classes), it's hard to understand what you're asking.

Comment: I'm fairly sure this does belong here, and not on meta. It uses SO as an example, but it's really a generic "how do you allow markdown securely" question

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried following the link? Brings you to a page where you have to click buttons (which generates POST requests) to actually log out.

You cannot generate POST requests from `<img />` tags. Which makes the WMD editor safe.

Comment: So what to do to prevent csrf in case of GET requests in markdown?

Comment: @Tomek If you're allowing GET requests to change state you're doing it wrong; they should be POST requests

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. sorry for my english :)

Comment: Also, this isn't a **Cross Site** Request Forgery